# Simple ajax call using MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do is to get my accordion to work using MVC. All I did was use the template of visual studios 2013 and added a view and put my html, javascript, jQuery code in the view because it worked in notepade++. I imported the scripts and everything.

What my program is trying to do is to do a simple Ajax to some local txt file data I have saved on my computer the data in the txt is put in a JSON format so my call should be working. But when I run my program IE doesn't even go to the call or maybe it goes to the call and doesn't work. When I remove the call completely and put an alert box in its place it reaches the alert but when I re-insert the ajax it doesn't call it.

So here is my code - what am I doing wrong?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>

        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "AccordianData.txt",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.numHeaders; x++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" + data.headerTitle[x]+ "</h2>");
                            $("<div><p>'" + data.content[x]+ "'</p></div>").appendTo("#container");
                        }
                        $("#container").accordion();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log("Ajax or parse error");
                    }
                })
                //$( "#container" ).accordion();

            });
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `"IE doesn't even go to the call or maybe it goes to the call and doesn't work"` - There's a pretty big difference between the two.  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Step through the code in your browser's debugging tools, monitor the network requests to see if the request is being made and what the server's response is.  Don't just give up and say "I don't know, maybe it's doing this or that", find out.

Comment: I don't know if I did it right but I clicked on the symbol on IE that looks like a wifi adapter and it says that I am getting a Http Get 200 so its going through right?

Comment: Why do you have `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`? You aren't making a POST request so you aren't sending any request body to the server, let alone one that is specifically JSON.

Comment: Is the success function firing (add a console.log statement in it to check)? Is the error function firing?

Comment: No the success nor the failer is firing and I commented out the contentType application/json

Comment: I can't think of any circumstance where neither of them would fire given that code and the request being made.

Comment: I reckon it's probably returning 404, press F12 and go to `Console`, then do your AJAX request.

Comment: Wow I am getting a 304 on my Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js, and a 404 on my Accordian data.

Comment: Okay so what is it that you really want to do with your accordian data? I think the best course of action would be to access a controller action and return the accordion data from that instead, as in reality the accordion data will be stored on the server anyway.

Comment: I just wanted to display the accoudian data very simply just so that I know how to use Ajax with MVC I figured once I got the Ajax call to work that I would then put the information properly in the contoller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aye I solved my own problem. the    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") in my Layout folder was conflicting with the  jquery script I had placed in my index view so once I removed it. the accordion showed up correctly and the Ajax call was made